# Http Form post in web hosted environment

Tags: php, http, web-hosting

I am newbie in PHP, HTML, MYSQL & web hosting. i have mamp setup on my development machine. Everything went well. When i put the file on the webserver things did not work.

here is the problem i am trying to solve:
i have http form with post methods call the php script and setup records in database.

```
 1. i have a HTTP form like this`<form action="addnewemployee.php" method="post">`. Its named in a file index.php.
 2. When i press the submit button, i get 404 not found for the file \addnewemployee.php.
```

everything is working on my local MAMP, but not on the production server.

cheers
Arun

Comment: The apache configuration for redirects is probably different between the two servers.  Check out what it is on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

you might have forgot to create a new file

addnewemployee.php

and put these code

```
<?php
var_export($_POST);
```

Comment: i am not creating any file addnewemployee.php is there already, what am i missing?